# How to update VsCode if it don't automatically update when I click download update

Tags: visual-studio-code

Before when I update it just automatically update and there's a button to restart after update. But now when I click download update it downloads a ZIP file.

Comment: Your explanation of the error seems a bit lacking , could you brief us more

Answer (score 1):

Help above vscode, penultimate option.Check for updates.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok now. I extracted the zip file and opened the code.exe and my vscode is updated.